# new Date() behaving inconsistently in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a JavaScript control consisting of 3 dropdowns to collect date of birth from users (don't ask me why we're not using a date picker)
A dropdown for day, month, and year. When all 3 dropdowns have a value selected, I collect the values and construct a date:

```
  var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.selectedYear, this.selectedMonth - 1, this.selectedDay));
```

I'm not sure why you need to subtract 1 from the month, I just copied that bit from existing codebase and it seems to work. I guess months have a zero-based index for whatever reason.

The obvious problem with these dropdowns is that the user can select an invalid date. There's nothing stopping them to select 31 for day and then select February. This will result in the date being shifted forward by a number of days, i.e. values 1999, 2, 31, would give me March 3rd, 1999. So I have a check in place:

```
if (d.getDate() != this.selectedDay) {
                d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.selectedYear, this.selectedMonth - 1, 0));
this.selectedDay = d.getDate();
```

If the day of month is different then my original value, it means the date has shifted, so I change the date to the last day of last month (hence the 0 for day) and then I update the value in the 'days' dropdown.

The strange thing is, I can't do this.selectedMonth - 1 in this second conversion. This would bring me all the way back to January 31st. So I have to do the following:

```
 var d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.selectedYear, this.selectedMonth - 1, this.selectedDay));
            if (d.getDate() != this.selectedDay) {
                d = new Date(Date.UTC(this.selectedYear, this.selectedMonth, 0));
                this.selectedDay = d.getDate();
            }
```

This works, but it's just mind-boggling to me. Why do months behave differently if I use 0 as a value for days instead of a valid day of month? Why would anyone implement it this way? Does anyone have a logical explanation?

Comment: It probably has to do with old-dying programming patterns.

This gives a good probable explanation :
https://www.quora.com/When-using-the-Date-constructor-why-is-the-month-argument-zero-indexed-but-the-day-argument-not

Comment: Well...[that's how `Date.UTC` works](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC). Not sure if that's logical enough.

Comment: _“I'm not sure why you need to subtract 1 from the month”_ — Yes, months are 0-based. You can look it up in the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date).

Comment: Please post all of the relevant code (HTML, CSS, JS) in a code snippet here in your question so we can replicate your issue and provide an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it's not the `month` field that's any different from the others: it's the `day` part that is the only one that is 1-indexed, as you can find in [the docs on `Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> Given at least a year and month, this form of Date() returns a Date object whose component values (year, month, day, hour, minute, second, and millisecond) all come from the following parameters. **Any missing fields are given the lowest possible value (1 for the day and 0 for every other component).**

(emphasis mine)

---

The incorrect assumption you made is that using `0` for the `day` part would represent the *last day of the month*. There's no such quirks to JS `Date`s!

Picking the day `0`, instead of the day `1`, merely offsets the `Date` you picked by **one** day. Just one full day before the first day of the month...
That would be the last day of the previous month.

---

If the month you want to select is `this.selectedMonth - 1`, its last day is obtained by doing the following:

- select the following month — that's `+ 1`, so: `(this.selectedMonth - 1) + 1`
- go back one day before the first — that's day `0`, one before the day `1`.

This is exactly what you're doing when you go:

```
//                ┌───── year ────┐  ┌───── month ────┐ day
new Date(Date.UTC(this.selectedYear, this.selectedMonth, 0))
//                                   │                │  │
//             ┌─────────────────────┘                │  │
//             the month after (this.selectedMonth - 1)  │
//                                                       │
//                        ┌──────────────────────────────┤
//                        the day before the first day (1)
```

Sometimes, even an ASCII picture is worth more than a thousand words .

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, months are zero indexed hence you need to subtract 1 from the calendar month number. You can make life easier by setting the values of the month options to their month index (0 to 11) rather than calendar month number (1 to 12). The displayed text can be the calendar month number or name.

To validate the input date values, you can just check that the month hasn't changed when creating the date.

I can't see why you're using Date.UTC, it will change the date for users east of Greenwich as for anyone with a positive timezone offset (or negative ECMAScript offset) 2019-10-01 UTC is 2019-09-30 local.

```js
let i;
let ySel = document.getElementById('inYear');
for (i=0; i<10; i++) {
  ySel.appendChild(new Option(2010+i, 2010+i));
}

let mSel = document.getElementById('inMonth');
'January February March April May June July August September October November December'
  .split(' ')
  .forEach((m, i) => mSel.appendChild(new Option(m, i)));

let dSel = document.getElementById('inDay');
for (i=1; i<32; i++) {
  dSel.appendChild(new Option(i, i));
}
  
[ySel, mSel, dSel].forEach(el => el.addEventListener('change', validateDate, false));
  
function validateDate(){
  let y = document.getElementById('inYear').value;
  let m = document.getElementById('inMonth').value;
  let d = document.getElementById('inDay').value;
  let date = new Date(y, m, d); // m is already zero indexed
  let errSpan = document.getElementById('dErr');
  if (date.getMonth() != m) {
    errSpan.textContent = 'Invalid date';
  } else {
    errSpan.textContent = date.toString();
  }
}
```

```html
Year: <select id="inYear"></select>
Month: <select id="inMonth"></select>
Day: <select id="inDay"></select><span id="dErr"></span>
```

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest to make year input first and required, after it has value enable month picker and then create new date object from where you would display day picker